# Querying All subscribers to identify subscribers which are removed from Synchronized Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to identify which subscribers are no longer part of the Synschronized Data Extension to be able to update their status in the All Subscribers List. I've used various queries, but I keep on getting 0 results.

An example is:

```
SELECT  s.SubscriberKey
FROM    ent._Subscribers s
            LEFT JOIN ent.Account_Salesforce a
                on a.PersonContactId = s.SubscriberKey
WHERE   a.PersonContactId IS NULL
```

I have a few test records, that are not part of the sync, but are part of the All Subscriber list, which I expect to show up, but none of them do.

Does anyone have tips on how to solve this use case?

Comment: All Subscribers is a record of those sent an email (or imported).  Sync'd DE subscribers would only appear in All Subs if either of those two things happened.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs This is indeed the case. They are synced and have received an email before, however they are now marked as unmailable in Salesforce CRM and therefore not synced to SFMC anymore. To make sure we are reflecting the same status in SFMC, so 'unsubscribed', I need to locate the subscribers who where part of the sync, but aren't anymore.

Comment: Were the emails sent with Person/ContactID as Subscriberkey? What filters on Account are present in Contact Builder?

Comment: Emails are/were sent with PersonContactId as SubscriberKey. The only filter we apply in the Connector is 'PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = true'

Comment: Did you mean `PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail = false` for your filter?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs We have found a workaround based on Salesforce Data entry events we have in place, for which the data extensions still contain the data we need. Thanks for your help anyways!